# Animation cycles in 3ds max 2010

Tags: animation, 3d-graphics

I'm new to animation. I have Max 2010. Basically I have a ball and it has keyframes where it bounces and moves 15 units forward I want a way to be able to add this animation as many times as I want so it bounces and always moves 15 more units. When I shift drag my keyframes, the ball moves 15 units, then quickly goes back and moves the same 15 units. I want it to be like a bip file where it can be added relative to the current position. (Essentially creating a generic ball bounce). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a '[relative repeat](http://www.escalight.com/tutorials/3dsmax-tutorials/repetitive-animation.html)' type of animation? [Escalight](http://www.escalight.com/tutorials/3dsmax-tutorials/) has a good collection of online tutorials.

If you are new to animation, I strongly urge you to work through some tutorials first, else you are going to be posting 10 new question here every day.  Some good starting points:

1. http://www.raminsoftworx.com/iart219/ - this is an excellent online resource - has good depth.  Check out the presentation for week 8.  This isite also has some other good references, books & online.
2. http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/3DS-MAX/Animation/1  - lots of visual examples.